# Access query or VBA code to move data from one table to another depending on first row unique identifier

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is it possible to write a query to loop through the rows of a two column table, checking the first column for a certain identifier and copy the data in the second column into a new table?

Example:

```
tblSurveyData
FirstColumn     Second Column
A0              John
A2              Smith
A3              05-01-1973

tblSurveyReport
FirstName   MiddleName  LastName    DateOfBirth 
John                    Smith       05-01-1973
```

Where A0 data would go to FirstName, A1 MiddleName, A2 LastName and A3 DateOfBirth. There are many more identifiers and fields but just as an example how would you do this with a query in Access or is VBA a better solution?

The only solution I came up with is the following VBA but this bypasses the two column table and tries to insert into the tblSurveyReport table. Unfortunately, it puts each piece of data into its own row which doesn't help.

```
If Identifier = "A0" Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport " _
            & "(FirstName) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & Info & "')"
ElseIf Identifier = "A1" Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport " _
            & "(MiddleName) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & Info & "')"
ElseIf Identifier = "A2" Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport " _
            & "(LastName) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & Info & "')"
ElseIf Identifier = "A3" Then
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport " _
            & "(DateOfBirth) " _
            & "VALUES ('" & Info & "')"
End If
```

However each piece of data is going into its own row and I need it all in the same row.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

TC

Comment: [`TRANSFORM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you tried anything already? It might help others to provide more useful questions if you include it...

Comment: Paul - Done. Marty, I'm looking into TRANSFORM but could use an example if you have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INSERT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with a SELECT statement

```
INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport(FirstName) SELECT FirstName FROM tblSurveyData where FirstColumn = 'A0'

INSERT INTO tblSurveyReport(MiddleName) SELECT MiddleName FROM tblSurveyData where FirstColumn = 'A1'
```

You could run this using a DoCmd, as a query in Access, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to get this solution to work but I am getting some Syntax issues. But this seems like a great solution once I figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: @TracyC - Sorry... had a typo in the table name

Answer (score 0):

You will need something that would link your records together.  What happens if the data gets re-sorted?  How would you know that all the info in your example should be in the same record?  I believe the only way to do something like this would be to create a 3rd field in your first table that determines which data belongs with which, something like a UserID.  Then the table would look like this:

tblSurveyData

```
FirstColumn     Second Column      UserID
A0              John               XX001
A2              Smith              XX001
A3              05-01-1973         XX001
```

Then you could create a preliminary query like:

```
Select DISTINCT UserID from tblSurveyData
```

Use that as your "pointer" query and loop through the results, and then you can pull all the records with each UserID out and copy them into the new table.  Or, you can inner join the "pointer" query and tblSurveyData, and then use a Crosstab query.  The easiest way to do that would be to use the wizard to create it, and then just copy the code into your VBA.

**EDIT:** For easier readability for future readers, the SQL for the query you're asking for in your comment is:

```
SELECT Max(IIf([Identifier]="A0",[IValue],"")) AS FName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A1",[IValue],"")) AS MName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A2",[IValue],"")) AS LName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A3",[IValue],"")) AS BDate FROM tblSurveyData;
```

You will need to change "First Column" in your sample data to "Identifier", and "Second Column" to "IValue" (or make the corresponding field name changes to the above SQL).  I have tested this and it worked perfectly, giving you one record with all 4 values in corresponding fields.  Once you've pasted that into a blank query, you can switch to Design View and change the query to an Append or MakeTable query and that will let you export the results to tblSurveyReport.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've been researching your suggestion but I'm rather new at this and am still a little lost. I should probably be more clear in my question. TblSurveyData is actually a temporary table that is used during an import from a file. It will not get re-sorted and it will only contain one set of information (for one UserID) with no duplicates ever. It is cleared out after each import. I need that second column from tblSurveyData to go to the correct columns of tblSurveyReport. Could you explain how I could pull the records and accomplish this? Thanks again.

Comment: Plug this in, and you can make it an Append query or a MakeTable query or something. The following query SQL assumes First Column is renamed as Identifier, and Second Column is renamed IValue. You may have to change the column names but the concept here has been tested and will work: SELECT Max(IIf([Identifier]="A0",[IValue],"")) AS FName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A1",[IValue],"")) AS MName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A2",[IValue],"")) AS LName, Max(IIf([Identifier]="A3",[IValue],"")) AS BDate FROM tblSurveyData;

Comment: This seems to be working. I'm going to play around with this solution. Thanks for the detail you provided Johnny!

Answer (score 0):

You could have simply two recordsets, like this:

- 1st recordset: rsSurveyData
- 2nd recordset: rsSurveyReport

The idea is to browse the first recordset along its records, and the second along its fields.

depending on the recordset object you are using (DAO or ADODB), the opening syntax will be slightly different, but you'll find all details in the help. I am using here the ADODB syntax for the 'Find', 'Move', and 'Update' methods. DAO recordsets need an extra 'Edit' method before changing the data. And I do not remember if the fields collection of the recordset object is indexed from 0 or 1 ...

Then:

```
rsSurveyData.moveFirst
rsSurveyReport.Find "FirstName ='" & rsSurveyData.fields("A0") & "'"
if rsSurveyReport.EOF then
    'do what you have to do when the record does not exist, for example:'
    rsSurveyReport.addNew
    rsSurveyreport.fields(1) = rsData.fields(1)
Else
    'you''ve just found the record that needs to be updated'
    for i = 2 to rsSurveyData.recordcount
        rsSurveyData.move i, 1    
        rsSurveyReport.fields(i)=rsSurveyData.fields(1) 
    next i
    rsSurveyReport.update
Endif
```

Comment: Philippe, I will play around with this solution as well. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: In terms of speed, this should be similar to SQL instructions. But using recordsets makes usually things more readable...