# How can we customize button in such a way that one button can delete items from table and same items be added in another table in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, button, sql-update, jbutton, ms-access-2016

I have two table tbl1,tbl2 ,one form contain one button while clicking that button need to be delete from tbl1 nad add to be in tbl2 in microsoft access?

Comment: Why? "Moving" records is usually a bad design. If you want to "archive" a record, just set a field then filter to exclude in query.

Comment: But if you really must, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621311/access-query-or-vba-code-to-move-data-from-one-table-to-another-depending-on-fir